# Generate Malformed Strings for Testing

Tags: java, php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

I'm using and contributing to a library (https://github.com/neitanod/forceutf8) to fix encoding issues in our system, and to guarantee that any encoding issues will be transparently fixed before they are displayed to the user.

I need some test cases, and what I would like is a function that takes a UTF-8 string and converts it into a malformed string. Then I can run it through my library to make sure it fixes it properly:

```
// psuedocode
strings = [ '공', '人', '', 'passé' ];

foreach ( string in strings )
    malformed = garble( string )
    print( string + " => " + malformed + "\n" )
```

Here are some examples of malformed strings:

- `"äºº" --> 人`
- `"ð´ " -->`  (a red ball—works in Safari)

---

Here's the raw hex data:

```
<?php
$strings = array( "äºº", "人", "ê³µ", "공", "ð´", "" );
foreach ( $strings as $string )
    echo " '$string' \t => '" . unpack( "H*", $string )[1] ."'\n";
?>
```

Output:

- `'äºº'  => 'c3a4c2bac2ba'`
- `'人'   => 'e4baba'`
- `'ê³µ'  => 'c3aac2b3c2b5'`
- `'공'    => 'eab3b5'`
- `'ð´'   => 'c3b0c29fc294c2b4'`
- `''    => 'f09f94b4'`

You can see that `人` is **e4 ba ba** and its characters can be found in the malformed string in between a few **c2**'s like so:

- c3a **4** c2 **ba** c2 **ba**

---

I hope this is clear enough.

One way that strings can be generated is to insert them into MySQL and then take them back out.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but you basically already answered your own question in this line: `One way that strings can be generated is to insert them into MySQL and then take them back out.` ?

Comment: Well, the data I had to deal with in MySQL was bad, so I was able to use that. However, I haven't been able to intentionally insert bad data without it happening correctly.

Comment: Well, working as an engineer, we normally hard code test cases manually as a test case should be consistent in order to produce useful results. In your case I'd do maybe 3 or 4 sets of tests that should be transformed and would put the rest of my attention to bordercase testing and such, to guarantee that there are no 'false' transformations

Answer (score 0):

You can false de- and encode your strings like this:

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

[..]

private static void malformedStringTest() {
    byte[] utf8bytes = StringUtils.getBytesUtf8(
              "This is a test\n" 
            + "äºº 人 ê³µ 공 ð´ \n"
            + "The above won't work.");
    String asciistring = StringUtils.newStringUsAscii(utf8bytes);

    System.out.println(asciistring);
}
```

it will output:

```
This is a test
������ ��� ������ ��� ���� ����
The above won't work.
```

You can adapt this code to test each string one by one.

Also look at the other static methods of org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils.